# UITableView header view

Tags: uitableview

I have 3 different instances of tableview in Nib, where I am displaying all these tableview in a page control. And delegate and data source for all the 3 tableview is same.

Problem here is, Header view is appearing in one tableview and disappearing in others when I change the Page of the UIPageControl ?

Any idea how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you have separate instances of the view being used as the header for each table view and/or are they generated dynamically? Since it's not possible for a view to be a subview of more than one view at a time, using the same view as a header for multiple table views will result in odd visual artifacts (views disappearing one place and showing up somewhere else).

Comment: thanks a lot Moore. It worked..

Comment: I've pasted substantially the same thing as an answer below. Please accept it if I've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not possible for a view to be a subview of more than one view at a time, using the same view as a header for multiple table views will result in odd visual artifacts (views disappearing one place and showing up somewhere else). You can add one header view per table view to your nib, or generate a header view for each programmatically, and assign them at run-time.